# Users can't cancel their own order

Tags: commerce

I'm using Drupal Commerce Kickstart to create an E-commerce website.

How can customers cancel their own order if they accidentally ordered some wrong product?

> [image: add cancel order button here]

Answer (score 0):

Find permission page (/admin/people/permissions) and You can give Authenticated users  permission to "Edit own Order orders"

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.Tried by giving permission. But user can't cancel their own order.

Comment: Read https://www.drupal.org/node/1419784 . I think this will help.

Comment: Yeah, I had checked that, that issue was still active.
I have an idea of using Drupal rules to update the order status.  But I want to know on which event we can trigger an action of updating status?